# Describe the characteristics of this function (where it is defined, continuous, diff, twice diff).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, continuity

Consider the function

$f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x/k)}{k}$

Where is $f$ defined? Continuous? Differentiable? Twice-differentiable?

My thoughts so far:

Initially I thought that due to its resemblance to the harmonic series that it would diverge, but then I went to graph it on https://www.desmos.com/calculator and it appears to converge properly for most (if not all) $x$. This confused me so I tried the Weierstrass-M Test but couldn't produce a suitable bound, $M_n$.

The graph seemed to show it was continuous. If indeed this function is defined and continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$, I think I can show its derivatives exist fairly easily and show that they converge uniformly to functions $f'$ and $f''$, respectively.

What else should I try in order to answer the above descriptive questions?

Comment: Hint: $|\sin(t)|\le|t|$.

Comment: generally, if $f(x) \sim x$ when $x\to 0$, then $|f(x)| < (1+\epsilon) x$ when $x$ is small enough,  and $\sum_k \frac{f(x/k)}{k}$ converges